# Flutter Pod player Shows Error while playing video message

Tags: flutter, podplayer

I'm Using Flutter Pod player Now It shows message "Error While Playing Video"  After Some times loading. App Log Shows As Below:-

E/flutter (25708): #59     PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:82:5)
E/flutter (25708):

I tried updating Pod player version

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

Source code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late PodPlayerController podPlayerController;
  Future<void> future = Future<void>.value();
  String networkFileURL = "https://shorturl.at/ruFK2";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final PlayVideoFrom networkSource = PlayVideoFrom.network(networkFileURL);
    podPlayerController = PodPlayerController(playVideoFrom: networkSource);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (Duration timeStamp) async {
        future = initialisePodPlayer();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    future = Future<void>.value();
    podPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initialisePodPlayer() async {
    await podPlayerController.initialise();
    print("Pod Player Initialised");
    podPlayerController.play();
    setState(() {});
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: future,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                  ? snapshot.hasError
                      ? Text("${snapshot.error}")
                      : PodVideoPlayer(controller: podPlayerController)
                  : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```